# Intellij stepping over whole code blocks instead of taking single steps

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

If I debug my code with Intellij and single step using <kbd>F8</kbd> it always jumps over whole code blocks.. If I don't place a break point in a block e.g. a `for` loop then Intellij will simply skip that.

```
val x = // ..

for(j <- 0 to 100) {
  // jumps over unless it has a break point in it
}

return x
```

I am not sure if I accidentally clicked a button that switched that behavior but that is definitely *too* intellij for my taste.

Can I change that behavior somehow?

Comment: I assume you are using the newest Intellij Idea version? It's 2016.1 right now, isn't it?

Comment: Mine here says `2016.1.1` from 29th of March 2016